# How should I replace jQuery UI dialog?

Tags: 8, javascript

I try to use jQuery UI dialog.
Based on [this](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/), I put this in a node:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $( function() {
      $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
    } );
</script>
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <p>
        This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.
    </p>
</div>
<p>
    Some stuff...
</p>
```

And it works! The popup window shows up automatically when the node is displayed.
But I noticed that jQuery is deprecated in Drupal 8.
So, how should I do the same thing in a more "Drupal" way?

[EDIT] Making progress...
@leymannx Using the 1rst example of Ajax Dialog Boxes page you provided, I get this working (see the screen capture).
My next step: how to have the dialog box displayed automatically when the page is reached without having to click the link?
[image]

Answer (score 4):

**jQuery hasn't been deprecated**. Some unused jQuery UI components have been deprecated in 8.8 and will be removed in Drupal 9.0. `core/jquery.ui.dialog` is not among them.

- [[8.8 issue] Deprecate unused jQuery UI components in favour of a suite of contrib modules](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3067251)
- [[8.8 change record] Deprecated unused jQuery UI asset libraries](https://www.drupal.org/node/3067969)
- [[9.0 issue] Remove deprecated jQuery UI components and fork remaining source code into core](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3087685)
- [[9.0 change record] jQuery UI source added to Drupal core and deprecated code removed](https://www.drupal.org/node/3089526)

Nonetheless there's the new Dialog API. For that you have to require the `core/drupal.dialog` library or the `core/drupal.dialog.ajax` library for more advanced stuff. Some examples can be found in the docs on [Ajax Dialog Boxes](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/ajax-api/ajax-dialog-boxes). The following sample requires the `core/drupal.dialog.ajax` library.

> This link opens /node/1 in a modal dialog box:
>
> ```
> <a class="use-ajax" 
>     data-dialog-options="{&quot;width&quot;:400}" 
>     data-dialog-type="modal" 
>     href="/node/1">
>     First node displayed in modal dialog.
> </a>
> ```

What you currently do in your code sample hasn't much to do with Drupal at all. To do it the Drupal way check the docs on adding JS/CSS to your module or theme first. You could attach the library simply to your theme or directly to all nodes of a given type for example.

- [Adding stylesheets (CSS) and JavaScript (JS) to a Drupal 8 module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-module)
- [Adding stylesheets (CSS) and JavaScript (JS) to a Drupal 8 theme](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-theme)

Comment: I hear you. I understand that I have to attach the library (`$something['#attached']['library'][] = 'core/drupal.dialog.ajax';`). But I don't know how to do that when I want it only on a specific node. Do I have to create a .js file with `$( function() {$( "#dialog" ).dialog();} );`in it and add both this file and the `core/drupal.dialog.ajax dependencie` to my module library? In this case, how to choose the node I want to display the popup when the nodeis displayed?

Comment: @gbmapo – I found https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/ajax-api/ajax-dialog-boxes where you can find more information on how to actually use it. From where you attach the library depends a little bit on the circumstances. Sounds a bit as if you might want to attach it to some field that references the other node maybe. But you could simply add it to your themes's info file as well.

Comment: I updated my question with the last results I get using your advice...

Comment: @gbmapo you can make jQuery to click the link for you on page load `$(".use-ajax").click();`

Comment: @No Sssweat I'm afraid my skills about jQuery are very limited... Where do I put `$(".use-ajax").click();`? In the modal.js I attached this way : `$variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'shared/modal';`? I tried but when I load the page, I get this error: TypeError: $ is not a function.

Comment: Make a new question on that, not enough room in comments to properly explain.